# How to configure DNS with ADDS server on window server 2012 r2?

Tags: networking, dns, domain, windows-server-2012-r2, static-ip

I have static single IP and multiple domains. Now I want, if some user goes to my domain URL It should point to my server, referring 80 ports and on same server.
how can I host multiple sites using 80 port?. I have more than 20 domains and I want to host on the same server with single IP address. I researched and found this can be done by creating a DNS record but how?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you configure the sites using host headers.

If you have two sites for instance named test1.com and test2.com, you would set the bindings for the first website to use 'All unassigned' for the IP address, 80 for the Port, and test1.com for the Host name.  You would then set bindings for the second website to use 'All unassigned' for the IP address, 80 for the Port, and test2.com for the Host name.

Here is more info regarding multiple bindings:

Add a binding to a site IIS 7
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

Managing Sites in IIS 7
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771341(v=ws.10).aspx

It is very different from how its done using linux for example. DNS usually forwards to IP's and not ports. Port binding is possible but then it would be test1.com on port 80 and test2.com on port 81 for example

Comment: the solution work?

Comment: @Nik Varma you can pretty much add hundred sites with 1 ip and port 80. It is not possible with port 443 however, SSL needs an unique IP. I edited the answer to more usefull articles.